# How to pass a request to a different IP address using Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am fairly new to nginx and trying to do something (and failing so far) which i dont' know if is something that can be achieved with nginx.
My nginx is set up with SSL and when client makes a call to it , will also be passing an IP of the actual server where the request should be handled and  which will send the response back.

The upstream server is on a different server where I don't know what's going to be the IP of that.. hence the request passes the target IP and the target IP has the server running on port 80. the upstream ip does not have URI  /gotoserver , it is just to let nginx know that it has to get the name parameter and pass the call to the appropriate server.

```
#this is where nginix is running with SSL on
server 
 {
  server_name  myserver.com;
  listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate  pathtocert;
ssl_certificate_ke keypath ;
#I want nginix to route the call ip x.x.x.x 
# which is being passed as request parameter named 'name'
location  /gotoserver?name=x.x.x.x
{
  set dserver $arg_name
  proxy_pass http://dserver:80

}
}
```

With the above configuration , it hits the server but looks like it is passing /gotoserver to the upstream and that server does not know about that URI.
If I hard code the IP in  the proxy_pass it works

```
location /
 {
   proxy_pass http://X.X.X.X:80
 }
```

Appreciate any pointers on how to make it work and my apologies if I missed some details.

Comment: Remove set and directly use proxy_pass http://$arg_name:80/

Comment: Thanks . I tried that but i noticed it is able to hit the upstream server but does not load the page . Meaning all the resources like  css or js show error 500 in the network console.  So it can reach the server but  can't find the relative resources.   please note that in case of $arg_name if I use  the actual server like http://x.x.x.x   it works .  i tried giving  both  http://$arg_name:80  and http://$arg_name:80/  but same issue.

Answer (score 1):

nginx matches only normalized `$request_uri` in `location` directives. Therefore it cannot match query arguments. Try the following:

```
location /gotoserver {
    proxy_pass $arg_name:80;
}
```

However, this approach is not optimal, sincce there is no validation on the `name` argument, and many invalid values can be there. There could also be security implications.

Comment: Oh yes, this is ripe for abuse.

Comment: Thanks . I tried that but i noticed it is able to hit the upstream server but does not load the page . Meaning all the resources like  css or js show error 400 /500 in the network console.  So it can reach the server but  can't find the relative resources.   Please note that in case of $arg_name if I use  the actual server like http://x.x.x.x   it works .  i tried giving  both  http://$arg_name:80  and http://$arg_name:80/  but same issue